# How to grep lines which does not begin with "#" or ";"?

Tags: grep

I want to grep `smb.conf` and see only lines which are not commented.

Comment: `testparm` do this better as this display default values too.

Comment: @F.Hauri Thank you. it is working as well. But it is also produce some unneeded (in my case) information, which should be grepped also...

Comment: superset: any regex: http://superuser.com/questions/655715/regex-does-not-begin-by-pattern

Comment: Another way through PCRE grep https://stackoverflow.com/a/45917459/3297613

Answer (score 223, accepted):

```
grep "^[^#;]" smb.conf
```

The first `^` refers to the beginning of the line, so lines with comments starting after the first character will not be excluded.  `[^#;]` means any character which is not `#` or `;`.

In other words, it reports lines that start with any character other than `#` and `;`. It's not the same as reporting the lines that don't start with `#` and `;` (for which you'd use `grep -v '^[#;]'`) in that it also excludes *empty* lines, but that's probably preferable in this case as I doubt you care about empty lines.

If you wanted to ignore leading blank characters, you could change it to:

```
grep '^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]#;]' smb.conf
```

or

```
grep -vxE '[[:blank:]]*([#;].*)?' smb.conf
```

Or

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[^;#]/' smb.conf
```

Comment: right answer is: `cat /etc/samba/smb.conf | grep ^[^#\;]` But anyway Thank you

Comment: Yeah, or you could use "quotes"; I edited that in subsequently.

Comment: or with quotes - as you just corrected :)

Comment: @denys You're wrong: goldilocks's response in not worst than your. .1 Please avoid using `cat ...| ` syntax!. .2 For whipping empty lines AND lines containing only space, maybe with comments U could use this: `grep -v "^ *\(#.*\|\)$" < smb.conf`

Comment: @denys For *samba*, did you try `testparm` command?

Comment: @F.Hauri: What's wrong with `cat ... |`?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg It's an useless fork. `cat file | grep "blah"` implie running two binaries through a *fifo*, while `grep "blah" <file` do exactly same and bind `file` *naturaly* to grep's `STDIN` . *[bash] useless cat* is a full featured subject of search through any search engine!  -> http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/useless-use-of-cat/ ... for sample

Comment: @F.Hauri: If it does exactly the same, how can it be useless?

Comment: It doesn't do *exactly the same*. It creates 2 processes and a pipe where 1 process is enough. Read the link given in @F.Hauri's last comment.

Comment: @rahmu: Do you habitually run out of processes? That syntax is intuitive and there is nothing wrong using it.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg If you use it, [you will be attacked by a velociraptor](https://www.xkcd.com/292/). On a more serious note, you can use the `<filename command` syntax which has the merits of both; you don't use `cat` and you get the filename before the command.

Comment: "Useless use of cat" is not *intuitive* -- I used to do it a lot.  It's *habitual*.  People new to the command line who learn to use grep correctly will not find it "counter-intuitive" vs. useless use of cat but, I think, more likely vice versa, because the issue is a pretty drop dead simple one to understand.  There is no possible advantage to useless use of cat *unless* you've become habituated to doing it (i.e., **you have a bad habit!**).

Comment: I did a similar thing to look for lines not starting with a quote, but `'^[^"]'` found the first line of the file, which *did* start with a quote!  Does `^` only work if there is a previous line?

Answer (score 5):

These examples might be of use to people.

```
[user@host tmp]$ cat whitespacetest
# Line 1 is a comment with hash symbol as first char

# Line 2 is a comment with hash symbol as second char
  # Line 3 is a comment with hash symbol as third char
        # Line 4 is a comment with tab first, then hash
        ; Line 5 is a comment with tab first, then semicolon. Comment char is ;
; Line 6 is a comment with semicolon symbol as first char
[user@host tmp]$
```

The first grep example excludes lines beginning with any amount of whitespace followed by a hash symbol.

```
[user@host tmp]$ grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' whitespacetest

        ; Line 5 is a comment with tab first, then semicolon. Comment char is ;
; Line 6 is a comment with semicolon symbol as first char
[user@host tmp]$
```

The second excludes lines beginning with any amount of whitespace followed by a hash symbol or semicolon.

```
[user@host tmp]$ grep -v '^[[:space:]]*[#;]' whitespacetest

[user@host tmp]$
```

Answer (score 5):

The pipe to grep in oliver nadj's answer may be eliminated by (assuming GNU `grep` or compatible):

```
grep -v "^\s*[#\;]\|^\s*$" <some_conf_file>
```

Comment: Second grep i@nadj's  looks useless , @goldilocks's answer was more than eough.

Comment: I agree that goldilocks's answer was correct. However, I also considered it useful to not show empty lines.

Answer (score 5):

Vim solution:

```
:v/^\s*[#\n]/p
```

I stumbled across this question when trying to find the vim solution myself.

Comment: This would also delete lines that starts with blanks.

Comment: True. I found that useful for config files as lines between comments otherwise fill up the output. If you'd rather keep the blank lines, change the `*` to `+` like so: `v/^\s+[#\n]/p`

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -v "^\s*[#;]" any.conf | grep -v "^\s*$"
```

that is what works for me. ignore commented or empty lines, even whitespace before hash mark or semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Here i got better one (assuming GNU `grep` or compatible):

```
grep -v '^[#;/%<]\|^\s*$' anyfile.conf
```

exclude for lines which begins with `#;/%<` which are in square brackets and the second filter after pipe is `\s*$` for blank lines.

Comment: In what type of conf files are `<` or `/` used for comments? I know a lot of conf file formats where `<` is everything but a comment. `!` is sometimes used like in X resource files.

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -v '^$\|^\s*#' temp
```

This one's a lot better, I got it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392869/how-to-print-a-file-excluding-comments-and-blank-lines-using-grep-sed

It assumes GNU `grep` or compatible.

Comment: The question also considers lines starting with `;` as a comment that should be removed.

Answer (score -2):

```
egrep -v "^#|^$" anyfile.txt
```

this command is to grep all info in file excluding comments and blank lines.

Comment: Notice that smb.conf also comments with `;`

Answer (score -3):

This should display you the file without those lines that begin with `#`:
`grep -v "^#" filename`

Comment: This does nothing to lines starting with `;`.