# grep to find "print" not "#print"

Tags: grep

In debugging, I use a lot of 'print' and commenting out it with '#print'. How can I use grep to find the line without '#' before 'print'?

```
# print <- not detect
#print <- not detect
abc # print <-- not detect
print <- detect
```

Comment: See [How to grep on source code without catching comments](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33131/how-to-grep-on-source-code-without-catching-comments) and [How to grep lines which does not begin with “#” or “;”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60994/how-to-grep-lines-which-does-not-begin-with-or) first.

Comment: Should it match (detect) `foo # bar print` ?

Comment: Should it match `print '#';`, `print ''; # here we print`, `str='#'; print` or `str='# print'`? There is probably no 100% safe expression without partially rebuilding the language's parser.

Comment: Try `grep '^[^#]*\bprint\b' input`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep '^[^#]*print'
```

Would be `print` only preceded by non-# characters.

Answer (score 1):

Classic solution:

```
grep -v '^#' <input |grep 'print'
```

Comment: The issue is that # can be anywhere in the line. I updated my post.

Comment: The solution greps for any line without the #, then checks for the word 'print'.

Comment: @prosseek Changing the requirements in a question after you receive an answer is not the right way. Better is to ask a new question. Never mind, luckily the solution works also for the changed requirements. But please *do not* change again the requirements. Ask instead a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is probably going to be to use two `grep`s, piped together.

```shell
$ grep 'print' <input | grep -v '#[[:space:]]*print'
```

With the file `input` containing your examples, that  gives:

```
print <- detect
```

That works for all of your examples. Which is probably good enough, but as manatwork and I point out in comments, its going to be very difficult to defeat all the edge cases with `grep`.

Comment: For this kind of job, weeding out 80% of the "should not detect" is probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning but wouldn't the ff work as well?

```
grep -v '#[ ]*print' input_file
```