# Grep all string which do not starts with number(s)

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm looking for grep to show all characters which do not starts with numbers.
I have done something like this:

```
grep -v '^[1-2]*[a-zA-Z]?' -o
```

but it do not work. 
Do you have any idea for some reg exp?

Comment: Using `-v` with `-o` causing `grep` produce no output.

Comment: What do you mean by show all **characters**? You mean lines which do not start with numbers, or do you want to strip out all the numbers from the input?

Comment: By default, `grep` uses *basic* regular expressions. This means that your `?` is being treated as a literal question-mark. Either escape the question-mark `\?`, or use the `-E` option for `extended` regular expressions, in which case `?` is a pattern character.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60994/how-to-grep-lines-which-does-not-begin-with-or

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`grep -v '^[0-9]'`

Will output all the lines that do not (`-v`) match lines beginning `^` with a number `[0-9]`

For example

```
$ cat test
string
string123
123string
1string2
$ grep -v '^[0-9]' test
string
string123
```

or if you want to remove all the words that begin with a digit

```
sed 's/[[:<:]][[:digit:]][[:alnum:]_]*[[:>:]]//g'
```

or with shortcuts and assertions

```
sed 's/\<\d\w*\>//g'
```

For example

```
$ cat test
one
two2
3three
4four4
five six
seven 8eight
9nine ten
11eleven 12twelve
a b c d
$ sed 's/[[:<:]][[:digit:]][[:alnum:]_]*[[:>:]]//g' test
one
two2


five six
seven 
 ten

a b c d
```

Comment: @mikeserv why? It removes every word beginning with a digit (as maybe asked in the original question)

Comment: Nope it does work. End on OS X (and maybe other BSDs) \> and \< are not working. For this reason I mentioned both versions. And I had to use the ugly one on my machine for the example.

Comment: From the man page `\>  Matches the null string at the end of a word.  This is equivalent to `[[:>:]]'.`

Answer (score 3):

It depends how do you define a *string* (e.g. if you count punctuation characters to string or not). Nevertheless you may start from something like

```
grep -Po '\b[^[:digit:]].*?\b' file
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove all words from a line that begin with a number with `sed` you can do:

```
sed 'x;s/.*//;G
     s/[[:space:]][[:punct:]]\{0,1\}[0-9][^[:space:]]*//g
     s/\n//'
```

...or, if you wanted only words which do not begin with numbers printed each on a separate line:

```
sed 'y/!\t "'"'?/\n\n\n\n\n\n/;/^[_[:alpha:]]/P;D"
```

...the above should do fairly well. You'll want to tailor the `\n`ewline `y///`translation for dividers you think are relevant. And, `sed` implementation depending, you might also want an actual `<tab>` in place of the `\t` backslash escape.

Comment: @don_crissti - Oh, yeah - I'll put that `!` ahead of the `'"'` swap, but if you're using `bash` you might want `set +H` or if `zsh` then `set -K`. In my opinion, any quoted `!` expansion is insanity. You can also use heredocs like `"${0#-}" <<\CMD\nyour cmd strings\nCMD\n` to get scripted behavior in interactive shells.

Comment: Thanks for the `"${0#-}" <<...` tip !

Comment: @don_crissti - If you use `"${0#-}" -s -- arg list <<\CMD\n...` you can also set the positional parameters at invocation. Using `"$@"` or `*` is often useful for me in place of `arg list`. And with `ln -s "$(command -v "${0#-}")" /tmp/new_name; cd tmp; new_name <<\CMD\n...` you can get a new `$0` and still handle stdin.